# Teechart space evently of the point series

Tags: activex, teechart

I am using Teechart to draw some point series, but the default canvas of the Teechart graph shown to be stretch entire area. I would like to add margin between Axis and plot point series. So, it look proportional to the  window.

Here sample codes:

```
    m_ptChart->GetWalls()->GetBack()->PutTransparent(FALSE);
    m_ptChart->GetWalls()->GetBack()->PutColor(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    m_ptChart->GetZoom()->GetPen()->PutColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    m_ptChart->SetTheme(tchartNS::ctDefault, tchartNS::cpSolid);

    // Setup Drawing canvas
    m_ptChart->GetCanvas()->PutUseAntiAlias(VARIANT_TRUE);
    m_ptChart->GetCanvas()->PutUseBuffer(VARIANT_TRUE);
    m_ptChart->GetAxis()->GetTop()->Maximum = (double)MaxPoints();
    m_ptChart->GetAxis()->PutDrawAxesBeforeSeries(VARIANT_TRUE);
}

// Add some series into the chart   
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    m_ptChart->AddSeries(scPoint);
    m_ptChart->Series(i)->Add(i*2, _T("Test1"), RGB(255 - i, 34, 128));
    m_ptChart->Series(i)->Add(i * 2, _T("Test2"), RGB(153 - i, 232, 173));
    m_ptChart->Series(i)->asPoint->GetPointer()->PutStyle((EPointerStyle)i);
    m_ptChart->Series(i)->asPoint->GetPointer()->VerticalSize = 10;
    m_ptChart->Series(i)->asPoint->GetPointer()->HorizontalSize = 10;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as in the *All Features\Welcome!\Axes\Isometric Axes* example at the features demo, available at TeeChart's program group. [Here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=5445&p=20428&hilit=isometric#p20428) you'll find an example on how to get the canvas handle in Visual C++. If that's not what you are looking for please provide more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. I am going to make source code changes and able to draw custom graph in background around the graph plot.